# Confirm Form Resubmission with Context Required Django

Tags: django

I have an account page that lets users edit their accounts. When the save button is pressed, I run the following code:

```
request.user.first_name = request.POST['first_name']
request.user.last_name = request.POST['last_name']
request.user.save()

context['alert'] = {
    'title': "Your information has been updated",
    'color': 'primary',
}
```

As you can see, I pass in context that, in my template, renders as an alert. However, when I refresh the page, it says: `Confirm Form Resubmission`

How can I get rid of this error? Thanks!

Comment: One normally performs a redirect, this is the Post/Redirect/Get pattern: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A successful POST request normally results in a redirect, this is the so-called [*Post/Redirect/Get* pattern [wiki]](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get).

In order to send messages to the user, you can make use of the [*messaging framework* [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/contrib/messages/). So you can add a message for a user, and then render it in the other view(s):

```
from django.shortcuts import redirect
from django.contrib import messages

def my_view(request):
    request.user.first_name = request.POST['first_name']
    request.user.last_name = request.POST['last_name']
    request.user.save()
    messages.success(request, 'Your information has been updated')
    return redirect('name-of-some-view')
```

Comment: Thank you for your response!! How do I parse the messages.success() in my template?

Comment: @JJT: see the [*displaying messages* section](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/contrib/messages/#displaying-messages). Normally it is better to include this in the "base template", such that you can render messages on all pages.